# Tower of Hanoi algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, computer-science

Tower of Hanoi

Lets say I have to find the most efficient way for a recursive tower of hanoi function except with 4 pegs.

Should obviously be faster than normal tower of hanoi

My algorithm is as followed:

If we have 5 disc it would look like this

```
     -                                               
    ---                                             
   -----                                            
  -------                                           
 ---------                                        
___________  ___________  ___________  ___________
```

I want to move n // 2 disc to one of the two spare stools

```
   -----                                            
  -------                      -                    
 ---------                    ---                    
___________  ___________  ___________  ___________
```

Now using the 3 stools that are left, I want to use the n - 1 approach (normal tower of hanoi) to get the remainder to the destination (I realized I put the n//2 in spare1 instead of spare2 but same thing overall)

```
                                          -----     
                  -                      -------    
                 ---                    ---------   
___________  ___________  ___________  ___________
```

Now simply putting the original n//2 to the destination

```
                                            -       
                                           ---      
                                          -----     
                                         -------    
                                        ---------   
___________  ___________  ___________  ___________
```

This gets the most efficient run time if the disc is 1 to 8, but after 9 theres apparently a better way. Is there any way way I could split the n to get a better run time?

run time:

best run time apparently (source: http://service.scs.carleton.ca/sites/default/files/tr/TR-04-10.pdf)

8: 33 moves

9: 41 moves

mine

8: 33 moves

9: 49 moves

Comment: Welcome to SO please take the [tour] and see how to [ask] and how to present code with [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let **Hanoi4(N)** be the number of movesit takes to move **N** disks with 4 pegs, and let **Hanoi3(N)** be the number of moves it takes to move **N** disks with 3 pegs.  We know that **Hanoi3(N) = 2^N-1**

I think you are correct that for every **N**, the best strategy will be to move some small disks onto a spare peg with **Hanoi4**, move the remaining large ones onto the target with **Hanoi3**, and then move the small ones ones to the target with **Hanoi4**.  For each **N**, then, the resulting formula would be **2*Hanoi4(a) + Hanoi3(N-a)**, where **a** is the number of small pegs we move off first.

Here's a simple program to figure out and print the best costs in python:

```
Hanoi3=[0,1]
Hanoi4=[0,1]

print "     N    Hanoi3   Hanoi4    a" 
a=1;
for N in range(2,20):
    Hanoi3.append(Hanoi3[N-1]*2+1)
    cost=2*Hanoi4[a]+Hanoi3[N-a];
    while a<N-1:
        c2 = 2*Hanoi4[a+1]+Hanoi3[N-a-1]
        if c2>cost:
            break
        a+=1;
        cost=c2;
    Hanoi4.append(cost)
    print '{0:6d}    {1:6d}   {2:6d}{3:5d}'.format(N,Hanoi3[N],Hanoi4[N],a)
```

Output:

```
 N    Hanoi3   Hanoi4    a
 2         3        3    1
 3         7        5    1
 4        15        9    2
 5        31       13    3
 6        63       17    3
 7       127       25    4
 8       255       33    5
 9       511       41    6
10      1023       49    6
11      2047       65    7
12      4095       81    8
13      8191       97    9
14     16383      113   10
15     32767      129   10
16     65535      161   11
17    131071      193   12
18    262143      225   13
19    524287      257   14
```

As you can see,  **N/2** does not calculate the best **a**.

You can play with the program here: https://ideone.com/tdT5R1

Comment: Thank you. It lead me to find the solution, it ain't exact but its very close. I used square roots for it